# Injecting the result of PHP code into a Javascript alert box 

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've recently been designing a website for a client, and have run into a slight difficulty in Javascript - I need to have either a `<?php include()?>`, or a form (the former being of more use) within a Javascript alert box.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks. :)

Comment: By Java you mean JavaScript, right?

Comment: Do you mean have custom input fields in an alert popup, like the one you get when you do alert("string"); Or like a form in a modal that pops over the rest of the content on the page?

Answer (score 1):

The `alert` function can only show plain text.

You need to use a fake modal dialog, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

**One PHP page**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<?php include("otherpage.php"); ?>");
</script>
```

**otherpage.php**:

```
echo "Hello, world";
```

Of course, the output of otherpage.php can only be plain text, and must have properly escaped quotes.  If you need to do anything else, you will need a different solution than JavaScript's `alert`.

Comment: You'd need to be *very* careful about the output of your PHP include, or capture it and escape it for use in a javascript context.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an alert box? Can it not be a lightbox?

The jquery UI dialog box may be of some help. it hasa dialog box with a form

[jQuery UI Dialog Box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Personally if you want a form in a box to pop up on click or something I would use a lightbox.

Hope this helps,